# I want to add the button of screenshot of my customer's page and then want it to save in a database and show it in a another page as dashboard

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html5-canvas

I tried using java script but it didn't work. I also tried `php`     `imagegrabscreen()`     but it demands URL whereas I have a customer's page URL different for everyone ex: [/member.php?email=shady@gmail.com&code=A101_123 .](http:///member.php?email=shady@gmail.com&code=A101_123%20.)
Basically I want to store user's screenshot so he can be able to see those images of his activity. So any solution?

Comment: There's no native mechanism to take screenshots using JavaScript, but you could try [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas) and then extract the image data.

Comment: Or you might be able to use a server-side solution that renders the page in a headless browser.

Comment: While searching on Internet I found some functions and php imagegrabscreen() function and even a website performing it as [link](http://www.take-a-screenshot.org/)

Answer (score 2):

I would recomment to take a look at [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/). It is a JavaScript solution that works on the client side. Only problem: It takes the current DOM from the user and builds a picture with the browser engine. So it is not 100% accurate, but pretty close.